# How do installers automatically detect whether they need to use a proxy?

Tags: python, windows, proxy, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use a Windows laptop for work. It has a VPN that allows me to access internal websites. However, when the VPN is on, I can't access the public Internet unless I configure my browser to use the correct proxy. If I need to run the `curl` command to download a file from the public Internet, it likewise needs to be explicitly given the `-x` argument to use the proxy, otherwise the download fails. This makes sense.

However, I've noticed that the Microsoft Visual Studio installer seems to work regardless of whether the VPN is on or not, and it doesn't need to be told what proxy URL to use. How is that possible?

Elsewhere, I read that Internet Explorer can autodetect the proxy settings by downloading a PAC file from `http://wpad/wpad.dat`. However, the PAC URL for my company is actually not `http://wpad/wpad.dat` so I'm not sure how the Visual Studio installer manages to work anyway.

I'm wondering if there's something in the Windows API that allows a program to query the current proxy settings so that it can automatically use whatever proxy is needed to access the URL that it needs to access. However, I am writing a Python script that is intended to work on platforms besides Windows as well, so ideally I am looking for a cross-platform API that can detect the current proxy settings without having to have the PAC URL hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer uses [WinINet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/about-wininet). Other applications can use IEs proxy settings when they call `InternetOpen` by specifying the preconfig flag.

`DetectAutoProxyUrl` can be called to get the WPAD location. Its flags indicate that it can use both DHCP and DNS when searching. The WPAD draft spec. can be found [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-wrec-wpad-01).

`InternetQueryOption` with `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY` or `INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION` can return the static proxy information.

Applications using WinHTTP may call `WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser` instead...